# Problemas con array_push PHP 7.2

Tags: php, array, php7

Saludos como están todos, tengo un problema y no se realmente que sucede, estas son mis versiones:

Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

PHP 7.2.11-4+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Nov  4 2018 05:10:57) ( NTS )

Estoy haciendo una consulta a mi base de datos y quiero organizar esos datos en un array para lo que estoy usando array_push pero no me devuelve ningún tipo de respuesta, estoy formando el array de esta manera:

```
array_push($arr,array(
    "codarticulo"    => $row4["codarticulo"],
    "precio_venta"   => $row4["precio_venta"],
    "descripcion"    => $row4["descripcion"],
    "unidad_medida"  => $row4["unidad_medida"],
    "codfamilia"     => $row4["codfamilia"],
    "multiplo_venta" => $row4["multiplo_venta"]
  ));header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($arr);
```

lo curioso es que en el host de producción funciona con normalidad y en mi equipo de desarrollo no, alguien me puede decir que es lo que pasa.

PD: el equipo de desarrollo tiene las mismas versiones que el de producción

Comment: el $arr esta declarado o tienes valores? si no $arr = array( // tu data ); echo json_encode($arr); es la mejor opcion!

Comment: si esta declarado por encima de un ciclo while para recorrer los datos de la consulta SQL

Comment: ¿Estás usando `mysqli` o `PDO`? No necesitas meter manualmente cada columna en el array, puedes hacerlo combinando por ejemplo `fetch_assoc` con `while`, así, dentro del `while` llenas el array asociativo haciendo simplemente esto: `while ($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc){$arr[]=$row;}` Como ya se ha comentado, antes de eso deberías verificar en tu código que la consulta trae datos. Y puedes depurar tu array antes de convertirlo a JSON, haciendo por ejemplo: `print_r($arr);` Si hay problemas de codificación el JSON no se creará bien, deberías aplicar codificación adecuada en la configuración.

Answer (score 0):

Si la salida que estás obteniendo está completamente vacía, lo más probable, es que el problema sea con json_encode y no con array_push.

Esta función falla silenciosamente y devuelve FALSE que, al ser convertido a string, se vuelve una cadena vacía.

El problema más común suele ser con el charset de la BBDD, de la tabla o de la conexión.

Para poder verificar si esta es la situación lo que te conviene es hacer un *print_r* o *var_dump* del array en vez de un *echo*.

Comment: si tienes mucha razón, el problema esta en el json_encode y no en el array_push, muchas gracias me puedes indicar como puedo solucionarlo para devolver un json

Comment: mi solución fue usar utf8_encode($row4["descripcion"]); y listo

Comment: Ten en cuenta que de esta forma lo único que haces es tapar el problema y no solucionarlo. La forma correcta sería verificar la configuración de la conexión y la bbdd para ver cual es el que está mal configurado. Saludos!